# C# ExecuteNonQuery ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm trying to perform an insert statement, however when I attempt to execute the command I'm getting an error:

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

When I print out the statement to manually test it successfully inserts the row. I'm wondering if anyone can spot what I'm missing to fix this error or an easy way to track and solve this myself.

SQL statement:

```
Insert into HP_PRINTING_MSG_TBL(SOFTWARE_VERSION, SPEC_VERSION, SOURCE, MESSAGE_NAME, DIAGNOSTIC_JOB_ID,EXTERNAL_JOB_ID, DISPLAY_JOB_NAME, JOB_TYPE, SUBMIT_NUMBER, IS_MAKE_READY,JOB_SUBMISSION_ID, LAST_STATUS, LAST_STATUS_TIMESTAMP, JOB_SOURCE, QUANTITY,FRAME_SORT_ORDER, INTERLEAVE_PATTERN, FRAMES_PER_COPY, QUEUE_LOCATION, STOP_AFTER_JOB,REQUIRE_CONTIGUOUS_COPIES, RESUME_MODE, SEPARATE_AFTER_JOB, QUALITY_MODE_REQUESTED, QUALITY_MODE_USED,ACTUAL_PRESS, PRESS_SERIAL, PRESS_PROFILE_NAME, FINISHING_RUN_OUT_FEET, SIDE_A_FEET,SIDE_B_FEET, CHIPOUT_LENGTH_INCHES, SIDE_A, SIDE_B, SIDE_A2,SIDE_B3, SIDE_A4, SIDE_B5, CHIPOUT_PATTERN, SIDE_A6,SIDE_B7, SPEEDBASEDCOLORREDUCTIONS, FIXED_CHIPOUT_ENABLED, FIXED_CHIPOUT_SIZE_IN, TYPE,PAPER_PROFILE_NAME, FINISHING_TYPE, FILES, CURRENT_COPY, COPIES_PRINTED_OK,COPIES_PRINTED_ERROR, ACTUAL_LINEAR_FEET_USED, FRAMES_PRINTED_OK, FRAMES_PRINTED_ERROR, FRAMES_PRINTED_OK8,FRAMES_PRINTED_ERROR9, UNITS, FIXER, BLACK, CYAN, MAGENTA,YELLOW, MICR, FIXER10, BLACK11, CYAN12,MAGENTA13, YELLOW14, MICR15, COPIES_WITH_ERRORS, FRAME_INCHES_ALONG_WEB,FRAME_INCHES_ACROSS_WEB, SEQUENCE, START_TIMESTAMP, SEQUENCE16, END_TIMESTAMP,CUSTOMER_JOB_ID)
values( pSOFTWARE_VERSION, pSPEC_VERSION, pSOURCE, pMESSAGE_NAME, pDIAGNOSTIC_JOB_ID, pEXTERNAL_JOB_ID, pDISPLAY_JOB_NAME, pJOB_TYPE, pSUBMIT_NUMBER, pIS_MAKE_READY, pJOB_SUBMISSION_ID, pLAST_STATUS, pLAST_STATUS_TIMESTAMP, pJOB_SOURCE, pQUANTITY, pFRAME_SORT_ORDER, pINTERLEAVE_PATTERN, pFRAMES_PER_COPY, pQUEUE_LOCATION, pSTOP_AFTER_JOB, pREQUIRE_CONTIGUOUS_COPIES, pRESUME_MODE, pSEPARATE_AFTER_JOB, pQUALITY_MODE_REQUESTED, pQUALITY_MODE_USED, pACTUAL_PRESS, pPRESS_SERIAL, pPRESS_PROFILE_NAME, pFINISHING_RUN_OUT_FEET, pSIDE_A_FEET, pSIDE_B_FEET, pCHIPOUT_LENGTH_INCHES, pSIDE_A, pSIDE_B, pSIDE_A2, pSIDE_B3, pSIDE_A4, pSIDE_B5, pCHIPOUT_PATTERN, pSIDE_A6, pSIDE_B7, pSPEEDBASEDCOLORREDUCTIONS, pFIXED_CHIPOUT_ENABLED, pFIXED_CHIPOUT_SIZE_IN, pTYPE, pPAPER_PROFILE_NAME, pFINISHING_TYPE, pFILES, pCURRENT_COPY, pCOPIES_PRINTED_OK, pCOPIES_PRINTED_ERROR, pACTUAL_LINEAR_FEET_USED, pFRAMES_PRINTED_OK, pFRAMES_PRINTED_ERROR, pFRAMES_PRINTED_OK8, pFRAMES_PRINTED_ERROR9, pUNITS, pFIXER, pBLACK, pCYAN, pMAGENTA, pYELLOW, pMICR, pFIXER10, pBLACK11, pCYAN12, pMAGENTA13, pYELLOW14, pMICR15, pCOPIES_WITH_ERRORS, pFRAME_INCHES_ALONG_WEB, pFRAME_INCHES_ACROSS_WEB, pSEQUENCE, pSTART_TIMESTAMP, pSEQUENCE16, pEND_TIMESTAMP, pCUSTOMER_JOB_ID)
```

C# execution:

```
  using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
    {
        cmd.Transaction = tx;
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("pSOFTWARE_VERSION", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.softwareversion) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.softwareversion;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSPEC_VERSION", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.specversion) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.specversion;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSOURCE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.source) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.source;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pMESSAGE_NAME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.messagename) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.messagename;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pDIAGNOSTIC_JOB_ID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = (object)DBNull.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pEXTERNAL_JOB_ID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.externaljobid) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.externaljobid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pDISPLAY_JOB_NAME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.displayjobname) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.displayjobname;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pJOB_TYPE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.jobtype) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.jobtype;       
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSUBMIT_NUMBER", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.submitnumber) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.submitnumber;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pIS_MAKE_READY", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.ismakeready) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.ismakeready;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pJOB_SUBMISSION_ID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.jobsubmissionid) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.jobsubmissionid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pLAST_STATUS", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.laststatus) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.laststatus;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pLAST_STATUS_TIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.TimeStamp).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.laststatustimestamp) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(parsedFile.laststatustimestamp);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pJOB_SOURCE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.jobsource) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.jobsource;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pQUANTITY", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.quantity) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.quantity;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAME_SORT_ORDER", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.framesortorder) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.framesortorder;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pINTERLEAVE_PATTERN", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.interleavepattern) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.interleavepattern;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAMES_PER_COPY", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.framespercopy) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.framespercopy;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pQUEUE_LOCATION", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.queuelocation) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.queuelocation;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSTOP_AFTER_JOB", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.stopafterjob) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.stopafterjob;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pREQUIRE_CONTIGUOUS_COPIES", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.requirecontiguouscopies) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.requirecontiguouscopies;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pRESUME_MODE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.resumemode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.resumemode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSEPARATE_AFTER_JOB", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.separateafterjob) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.separateafterjob;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pQUALITY_MODE_REQUESTED", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.qualitymoderequested) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.qualitymoderequested;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pQUALITY_MODE_USED", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.qualitymodeused) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.qualitymodeused;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pACTUAL_PRESS", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.actualpress) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.actualpress;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pPRESS_SERIAL", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.pressserial) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.pressserial;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pPRESS_PROFILE_NAME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.pressprofilename) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.pressprofilename;                
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFINISHING_RUN_OUT_FEET", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.finishingrunoutfeet) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.finishingrunoutfeet;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_A_FEET", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.recoverysideafeet) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.recoverysideafeet;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_B_FEET", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.recoverysidebfeet) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.recoverysidebfeet;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCHIPOUT_LENGTH_INCHES", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.chipoutlengthinches) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.chipoutlengthinches;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_A", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.colorsidea) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.colorsidea;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_B", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.colorsideb) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.colorsideb;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_A2", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.bondingsidea) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.bondingsidea;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_B3", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.bondingsideb) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.bondingsideb;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_A4", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.micrsidea) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.micrsidea;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_B5", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.micrsideb) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.micrsideb;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCHIPOUT_PATTERN", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.chipoutpattern) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.chipoutpattern;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_A6", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.spitbargapsidea) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.spitbargapsidea;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSIDE_B7", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.spitbargapsideb) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.spitbargapsideb;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSPEEDBASEDCOLORREDUCTIONS", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.speedbasedcolorreductionpercentscaled) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.speedbasedcolorreductionpercentscaled;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFIXED_CHIPOUT_ENABLED", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.fixedchipoutenabled) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.fixedchipoutenabled;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFIXED_CHIPOUT_SIZE_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.fixedchipoutsizein) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.fixedchipoutsizein;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pTYPE", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.papertype) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.papertype;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pPAPER_PROFILE_NAME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.paperprofilename) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.paperprofilename;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFINISHING_TYPE", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.finishingtype) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.finishingtype;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFILES", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.files) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.files;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCURRENT_COPY", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.currentcopy) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.currentcopy;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCOPIES_PRINTED_OK", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.copiesprintedok) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.copiesprintedok;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCOPIES_PRINTED_ERROR", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.copiesprintederror) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.copiesprintederror;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pACTUAL_LINEAR_FEET_USED", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.actuallinearfeetused) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.actuallinearfeetused;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAMES_PRINTED_OK", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideaframesprintedok) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideaframesprintedok;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAMES_PRINTED_ERROR", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideaframesprintederror) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideaframesprintederror;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAMES_PRINTED_OK8", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebframesprintedok) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebframesprintedok;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAMES_PRINTED_ERROR9", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebframesprintederror) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebframesprintederror;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pUNITS", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.units) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.units;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFIXER", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideafixer) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideafixer;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pBLACK", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideablack) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideablack;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCYAN", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideacyan) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideacyan;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pMAGENTA", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideamagenta) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideamagenta;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pYELLOW", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideayellow) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideayellow;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pMICR", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sideamicr) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sideamicr;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFIXER10", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebfixer) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebfixer;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pBLACK11", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebblack) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebblack;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCYAN12", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebcyan) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebcyan;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pMAGENTA13", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebmagenta) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebmagenta;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pYELLOW14", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebyellow) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebyellow;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pMICR15", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.sidebmicr) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.sidebmicr;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCOPIES_WITH_ERRORS", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.copieswitherrors) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.copieswitherrors;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAME_INCHES_ALONG_WEB", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.frameinchesalongweb) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.frameinchesalongweb;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pFRAME_INCHES_ACROSS_WEB", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.frameinchesacrossweb) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.frameinchesacrossweb;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSEQUENCE", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSTART_TIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.TimeStamp).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.startprintingtimestamp) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(parsedFile.startprintingtimestamp);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pSEQUENCE16", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pEND_TIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.TimeStamp).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.endprintingtimestamp) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(parsedFile.endprintingtimestamp);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pCUSTOMER_JOB_ID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = util.IsNull(parsedFile.customerjobid) ? (object)DBNull.Value : parsedFile.customerjobid;                
                PrintOracleCommand(cmd);                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Can you compare your table schema against whatever value you have within your `sqlStmt` value? Can you also add to the question what's in that variable? I basically want to see what's in the `Insert into [table] (x, y)`... all your field names should match the schema. The error (according to oracle) is because the name of a column does not match the a column from the schema...

Comment: "When i print out the statement to manually test it successfully inserts the row" how do you set parameter values in this case? A reason could be that a parameter name incidentally matches a column name from schema. to avoid such collisions, it is advisable to use a different prefix, for example the colon, so ":CUSTOMER_JOB_ID".

Comment: @dlatikay the PrintOracleCommand(cmd); loops through the parameters and performs a find replace on the parameter name to parameter value in the sql statement

Comment: ok. that takes away the cause of the collision. I suggest to keep dividing the list of columns and parameters in the statement in halves until it works, then add parts again until you've identified the culprit column (of course this is possible only if the majority of columns is nullable, therefore for better ideas please post your *describe table*)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no C# expert, but aren't you missing bind variable indicators here? ie, isn't your SQL text meant to be:

```
INSERT INTO HP_PRINTING_MSG_TBL 
  (SOFTWARE_VERSION, SPEC_VERSION, SOURCE, MESSAGE_NAME,  ...) 
VALUES 
  (:pSOFTWARE_VERSION, :pSPEC_VERSION, :pSOURCE, :pMESSAGE_NAME, ... )
```

Otherwise the "pSOFTWARE_VERSION" and the like will be interpreted as columns rather than variables to be bound.